# Как вывести уникальные данные из массива по id, когда список id тоже в массиве?

Tags: php

Собрал данные в одну переменную так:

```
    $items = array_merge($one, $two, $three, $four, $five);
```

Массив выглядит так:

```
array(43) {
  [0]=>
  object(Item)#2 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(25) {
      ["isMon"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["rate"]=>
      int(53)
      ["id"]=>
      int(200378)
      ["title"]=>
  string(180) "Title"
...
```

Массив с **уникальными id** `$unique_id` выглядит так:

```
    array(30) {
      [0]=>
      int(200)
      [1]=>
      int(203)
      [2]=>
      int(198)
      [3]=>
      int(207)
      [4]=>
      int(185)
      [5]=>
      int(199)
    }
```

Как получить уникальные данные по id из $items?

Comment: Обойти `$items` и проверить есть ли ИД в массиве `$unique_id`.

Comment: Очень много времени потратил, но так ине смог его корректно обойти.

Comment: Обычный `foreach` еще ни разу не подводил. Ну и желательно свой код показать, что там за некорректность.

Comment: У меня дубли появляются, кроме id. Не получается коректно задать `foreach ($items as $item) {` c `$unique_id`

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял ваш вопрос, поэтому напишу три ответа:
1)Если значение из $unique_id это ключ в $items:

```php
<?php
foreach ($unique_id as $id)
    var_dump($items[$id]);
```

2)Если ключ из $unique_id это ключ в $items:

```php
<?php
foreach ($unique_id as $id => $id2)
    var_dump($items[$id]);
```

3)Если значение из $unique_id это значение с ключём "id" из какого-то массива в $items:

```php
<?php
foreach ($unique_id as $id) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item["id"] == $id)
            var_dump($item);
    }
}
```